# Dealing with contours and bounding rectangle in OpenCV 2.4 - python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am working with openCv and python and I am dealing with Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors.
I have found this blog: http://opencvpython.blogspot.it/2012/06/contours-2-brotherhood.html
that's very helpful and I have tried with a black and white image to drawing a bounding rectangle and it works.
But now from an image i extract, for example, the yellow color and on that i would like to draw a bounding rectangle. The problem is that the black and white image is not uniform it has some noise and like that the code doesn't recognize the whole shape.

[image: origianl image]

[image: black and white image]

[image: final image]

And this is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('shot.bmp')
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
COLOR_MIN = np.array([20, 80, 80],np.uint8)
COLOR_MAX = np.array([40, 255, 255],np.uint8)
frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, COLOR_MIN, COLOR_MAX)
imgray = frame_threshed
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(frame_threshed,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt=contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("Show",im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Erode and then dilate. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Comment: Your original, colour, image doesn't look very clear, maybe this is causing the noise

Comment: yes it is not clear, i took it from a webcam because my last gol is to draw a rectangle in that yellow object in real time.
I will try with Eroding and Dilating!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since your original image is fairly noisy, a simple fix is to remove some of the noise using `cv2.medianBlur()` This will remove small noise areas in your original image, and leave you with only one contour. The first few lines of your code would look like this:

```
im = cv2.imread('shot.bmp')
im = cv2.medianBlur(im,5)    # 5 is a fairly small kernel size
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

However, this method is not the most robust because you must manually specify a kernel size, and the line `cnt=contours[0]` in your code assumes that the contour of interest is the firs in the list of contours, which is only true if there is only one contour. A more robust method is to assume that you are interested in the *largest* contour, which will allow you to compensate for even moderate noise.

To do this, add the lines:

```
# Find the index of the largest contour
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]
```

after the line:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Resulting in this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('shot.bmp')
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
COLOR_MIN = np.array([20, 80, 80],np.uint8)
COLOR_MAX = np.array([40, 255, 255],np.uint8)
frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, COLOR_MIN, COLOR_MAX)
imgray = frame_threshed
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(frame_threshed,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find the index of the largest contour
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("Show",im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Both of these methods give a result with a correct bounding box:

[image: Bounding Box Result]

**N.B.**
As of `OpenCV` 3.x the `findContours()` method returns 3 results (as can be seen [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)), so the additional return value should be caught like:

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPL‌​E)
```

Comment: `_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` should be the new syntax just in case anyone came across with reported error: `too many values to unpack` if you are using opencv 3 and python 3. See ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504964/opencv-python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack

Comment: I consider @Puriney 's comment really important, as there are several other question in SO that have originated from this problem. The question should be edited to include so

Comment: Upvoted this answer because it was the first help I found about `cv2.boundingRect` and the value it returns. OpenCV documentation lacks many of crucial little details like this...

Comment: Any idea how this can be modified to find a rotated bounding rectangle?