# OpenCV Python: cv2.findContours - ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm writing an opencv program and I found a script on another stackoverflow question: [Computer Vision: Masking a human hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752006/computer-vision-masking-a-human-hand/14756351#14756351)

When I run the scripted answer, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "skinimagecontour.py", line 13, in <module>
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

The code:

```
import sys
import numpy
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('Photos/test.jpg')
im_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

skin_ycrcb_mint = numpy.array((0, 133, 77))
skin_ycrcb_maxt = numpy.array((255, 173, 127))
skin_ycrcb = cv2.inRange(im_ycrcb, skin_ycrcb_mint, skin_ycrcb_maxt)
cv2.imwrite('Photos/output2.jpg', skin_ycrcb) # Second image

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000:
        cv2.drawContours(im, contours, i, (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.imwrite('Photos/output3.jpg', im)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I got the answer from the OpenCV Stack Exchange site. [Answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/40329/python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack/)

THE ANSWER:

> I bet you are using the current OpenCV's master branch: here the return statements have changed, see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours.
>
> Thus, change the corresponding line to read:
>
> ```
> _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
> ```
>
> Or: since the current trunk is still not stable and you probably will run in some more problems, you may want to use OpenCV's current stable version 2.4.9.

Comment: I don't understand  how to fix it?

Comment: @grep there is that 3rd return statement. compare the one in question and the answer lines

Answer (score 50):

This works in **all** `cv2` versions:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
```

**Explanation**: By using `[-2:]`, we are basically taking the last two values from the `tuple` returned by `cv2.findContours`. Since in some versions, it returns `(image, contours, hierarchy)` and in other versions, it returns `(contours, hierarchy)`, `contours, hierarchy` are always the last two values.

Comment: ahh-mazinnnnnnn

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: It's amazing hack

Answer (score 15):

You have to change this line;

```
image, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 2 years ago, and already had an accepted solution. And at that, you don't tell him what he has to change the line **to**. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a dramatically better alternative approach to the problem :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm using python3.x and opencv 4.1.0
i was getting error in the following code :

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

ERROR : too many values to Unpack
```

then i came to know that above code is used in python2.x
SO i just replaced above code with below one(IN python3.x) by adding one more '_' in the left most side 
have a look

```
_,cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: The simplest solution

Answer (score 5):

The thing you need to do is just add '_' where you are not using the required var , originally given by:

`im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

to

`_ , contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

Here the original doc is given:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Answer (score 2):

python is right.
you cannot unpack 3 values from the turple and place them in a turple of two

`contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

use

`img, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

Answer (score 2):

@Safwan has provided a simple hack by choosing the last two tuples returned by `cv2.findContours()` function. But what if you want all the values returned from every tuple of the function independent of the version of `cv2`?

The following snippet will work irrespective of the OpenCV version (2, 3 or 4) installed in your system/environment and will also store all the tuples in individual variables.

- OpenCV version 2 & 4, return 2 variables: contours and its hierarchy
- OpenCV version 3, returns 3 variables: input image, contours and its hierarchy

First, get the version of OpenCV installed (we don't want the entire version just the major number ***either 2, 3 or 4***) :

```
import cv2
major_version = cv2.__version__[0]
```

Based on the version either of the following two statements will be executed and the corresponding variables will be populated:

```
if major_version == '4' | major_version == '2':
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

elif major_version == '3':
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

The `contours` can be used for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

No big deal, just you might be using open-cv 3.something, which returns 3 values at the point of error and you must be catching only 2, just add any random variable before the contours variable -

```
_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is:

> not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

then use:

```
ctrs,hier=cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

instead of

```
_,ctrs,hier=cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```