# Python / Contour OpenCV returns "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm having a problem with this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html
Indeed, I encounter this error when I try to execute this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("onepoint.png", 0)

canny_img = cv2.Canny(img,150,200)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(canny_img,127,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
print M
```

Here is the error:

```
  File "contours.py", line 13, in <module>
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I do not understand why this error occurs. I understand that `cv2.findContours (thresh, 1, 2)` returns to me 3 "arrays", but why? If a person at the kindness to explain to me I am a taker :(

I'm trying to frame the words of this image:

[image: picture]

I'm totally new to OpenCV, I guess you'll understand,

Thank in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV python: ValueError: too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504964/opencv-python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Comment: I looked at this link before posting my question, but I did not find a clear explanation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change it to

```
im, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```

Or, if you only care about the contours:

```
(_, contours, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```

The function has changed in `OpenCV 3`.

Comment: I understand thank you :) But why it returns me 3 arrays and not 2 as on the tutorial?

Comment: @CorentinMar because the tutorial was written for an older version of OpenCV which only returns two values (as Jan mentioned, the function has changed in OpenCV 3). Note in the [3.0 documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) you can see that there are three return values and not two, [as there was in 2.4](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours).