# Template matching from screen capture

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to Python but want to learn it a bit so I decided to create a program
with template matching from desktop input.

Can any one help with this ? How to write template matching with stream from desktop ?

```
import time

import cv2
import mss
import numpy

template = cv2.imread('template.jpg', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        # cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        cv2.imshow('OpenCV/Numpy grayscale', cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY))

        # Print fps
        print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Search template in stream

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I noticed that you did not apply any edge-detection to your template image. The edge-detection is not necessary but useful for finding the features of the template image.

Assume I have the following image:

[image]

To detect the above template image precisely I should be applying an edge detection algorithm.

```py
template = cv2.imread("three.png")
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
```

[image]

I should also apply edge detection to the stream from desktop.

```py
img = sct.grab(mon)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
```

[image]

Check if the template matches with the captured image

```py
result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
(_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
```

If template image matched in the stream from desktop then get the coordinates.

```py
(_, maxLoc, r) = found
(startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
(endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + w) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + h) * r))
```

Finally draw the rectangle for displaying the location:

```py
cv2.rectangle(img, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (180, 105, 255), 2)
```

Result:

[image]

From above we see that the our template 3 value is matched on the stream from desktop.

Code:

```py
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from mss import mss

template = cv2.imread("three.png")
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(h, w) = template.shape[:2]

start_time = time.time()
mon = {'top': 200, 'left': 200, 'width': 200, 'height': 200}
with mss() as sct:
    while True:
        last_time = time.time()
        img = sct.grab(mon)
        img = np.array(img)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
        
        found = None

        for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
            resized = imutils.resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
            r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

            if resized.shape[0] < h or resized.shape[1] < w:
                break

            edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
            cv2.imwrite("canny_image.png", edged)
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
            (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

            if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
                found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

        (_, maxLoc, r) = found
        (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
        (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + w) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + h) * r))

        cv2.rectangle(img, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (180, 105, 255), 2)

        print('The loop took: {0}'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        cv2.imshow('test', np.array(img))

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why is canny (edge detection) necessary here? If I am understanding correctly, canny helps you remove noise so you only keep the relevant pixels of the image you are matching.

So what it does here in a sense is only removing the background as per the threshold of your choice?

Comment: Canny is not necessary here. If you re-read my answer you can see the line "The edge-detection is not necessary but useful for finding the features of the template image." You can use other edge-detection algorithms like gaussian-blur, sobel, scharr etc. My aim was to find the features of the current selected area. Therefore I applied edge detection.  For more https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d96/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html

Answer (score 3):

Let *untitled.png* be a file storing the image

[image]

Here is a working program. I used the following to put it together,

[OpenCV Org: Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)

[Taking screenshots with OpenCV and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/01/taking-screenshots-with-opencv-and-python/)

[OpenCV python: ValueError: too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504964/opencv-python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

```
import os
import cv2               as cv
import numpy             as np
import pyautogui
import time
import winsound          # for sound
from matplotlib          import pyplot as plt

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Mike\\\Desktop")
img = cv.imread('untitled.png',0)
img_piece = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
c, w, h = img_piece.shape[::-1]

while 1:
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()
    template  = cv.cvtColor(np.array(pic), cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    meth = 'cv.TM_CCOEFF'
    method = eval(meth)
    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv.matchTemplate(img_piece,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(res)
    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    if max_val > 66000000.0:
        print(max_val, top_left, bottom_right)
        winsound.Beep(888, 111)
        if 1:
            plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
            plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
            plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
            plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
            plt.suptitle(meth)
            plt.show()        
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the basic code to perform a match template. Place it below `img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))` and it will run every frame.

```
# create grayscale of image - because template is also grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# perform match
res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,template ,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
# get coordinates of best match
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = min_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
# draw red rectangle over original screen capture
cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right,(0,0,255),3)
# display image
cv2.imshow('Result',img)
```

You can find some more info on matchTemplate [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)