# What is the purpose of `cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]` when finding contours using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV in Python to find the contours of an image. I am using the below code which seems to be pretty standard for this task:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[1])
```

I'm struggling to understand the purpose of this line:

```
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
```

The code works as intended, but why is this line necessary?

If I comment out that line and just run the first and third lines of the code above, like so:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[1])
```

then I receive the following error message:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[56], line 2
      1 #cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
----> 2 cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[1])

Cell In[56], line 2, in <lambda>(x)
      1 #cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
----> 2 cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[1])

error: OpenCV(4.8.1) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'boundingRect'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - array is not a numerical tuple
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'array'
```

Comment: Are you asking **what** that line of code does, or are you asking **why** it does it?

Comment: cv2.findCountours returns 3 things in the opencv-3.x, coutours being the second value in the returned tuple whereas the same function in opencv-4.x returns just two seconds, counts being the first element of the returned tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV Python: cv2.findContours - ValueError: too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504964/opencv-python-cv2-findcontours-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Answer (score 0):

This is so that the code works with version 3.x `cv2`  `im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(` and with `4.x` `contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(`. [Doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html).