# Apply cv2.boundingRect on np.array

Tags: python, opencv

How to apply `cv2.boundingRect` to a `np.array` of points ?
The following code produces an error.

```
points = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=np.float32)
import cv2
cv2.boundingRect(points)
```

Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (The image/matrix format is not supported by the function) in cvBoundingRect, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp, line 97

File "<ipython-input-23-42e84e11f1a7>", line 1, in <module>
  cv2.boundingRect(points)
error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:970: error: (-210) The image/matrix format is not supported by the function in function cvBoundingRect
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `cv2.boundingRect(cv2.cv.fromarray(points))` but that doesn't seem to work either. returns `TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

Comment: I tried your code and it gave me the this bounding box without error (1, 2, 3, 3) which seems true. However, my CV version is '3.1.0-dev'.

Answer (score 3):

The Python bindings of the 2.x versions of OpenCV use slightly different representation of some data than the ones in 3.x.

From existing code samples (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507192/3962537) on SO), we can see that we can call `cv2.boundingRect` with a en element of the list of contours returned by `cv2.findContours`. Let's have a look what that looks like:

```
>>> a = cv2.copyMakeBorder(np.ones((3,3), np.uint8),1,1,1,1,0)
>>> b,c = cv2.findContours(a, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
>>> b[0]
array([[[1, 1]],

       [[1, 3]],

       [[3, 3]],

       [[3, 1]]])
```

We can see that each point in the contour is represented as `[[x, y]]` and we have a list of those.

Hence

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

point1 = [[1,2]]
point2 = [[3,4]]

points = np.array([point1, point2], np.float32)

print cv2.boundingRect(points)
```

And we get the output

```
(1, 2, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
points = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=np.float32)[:,np.newaxis,:]
import cv2
cv2.boundingRect(points)
```

You just need to add another axis, so the function will know it is a point list and not a 2d array.